# Cборка Go под 64 битную систему на 32 битной ситеме

Tags: golang, сборка

Возможно ли собрать код Go для 64 битной системы из под 32? Что для этого надо?

Использую eclipce. Выставил переменное окружение в ide и обычное (`GOARCH=amd64`), все равно собирается 32 битная версия.

Comment: Вопрос на засыпку - **зачем**?

Comment: Все очень просто. На моем ПК Ubuntu х32, а на результирующем сервере Ubuntu x64. Тащить на сервер Go-библиотеки и собирать там все не очень хочется.

Comment: Скорее всего (99.9999%) даже если вы запустите компиляцию под 64x на 32x ОС - вы получите ошибку

Comment: Не знаю, не знаю, я на x86_64 под mips кросс-компилировал и никаких ошибок не было. Правда, не Go, а C, но какая разница? Увы, с тем как в Go делают кросс-компиляцию, увы, я не знаком. По идее не `8g` а `6g` надо вызывать и все будет, а Makefile только обертка для этого.

Comment: @drdeaman - что такое Makefile я знаю и то, что это просто обвертка - тоже. За все время я пытался собрать x64 под x32 раз 8 и без толку, возможно я не достаточно извращался, не спорю. Но, даже если это возможно, ИМХО, в этом случае заниматься этой ерундой - пустая трата времени...

Answer (score 2):

Наоборот точно можно, но нужны библиотеки для 32-битного кода.
Соответственно тут тоже могут понадобиться библиотеки для 64-битного кода (если их нет в репозитории - надо будет настраивать руками).

Попробуйте скачать Go 1.5 - там кросс-компиляция сделана уже заметно лучше и никаких внешних зависимостей для неё не требуется (например я из Windows компилирую бинарники для Linux, до 1.5 требовались пляски начиная с 1.5 - всё хорошо).

Второй вариант:
просто компилировать 32-битные бинарники - они на 64битной системе тоже будут работать. Если вам не требуется в работе больше 2Гб памяти конкретно для вашей программы думаю что разницы не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Имхо, там нужно сначала кросс-компилятор подготовить. Может, поможет: [An introduction to cross compilation with Go](http://dave.cheney.net/2012/09/08/an-introduction-to-cross-compilation-with-go)